# Tensor Product of a polynomial quotient field with itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, integral-domain

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the rational numbers, and let $k = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-2)$. Describe the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $k \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} k$ as explicitly as possible. Is it a domain?

We have been told to use the fact that, for any R-algebra $S$ ($\phi: R \to S), $
$$R[X]/f(x) \otimes_R S = S[X]/f^{\phi}(x)$$ where $f^{\phi}(x)$ denotes the polynomial obtained by applying $\phi$ to the coefficients of $f(x)$. 
Using this, I can see that $k \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} k \equiv k[Y]/(Y^3-2)$. But I am not sure how to proceed in the problem.

Comment: Observe that $Y^3-2=(Y-\sqrt[3]2)(Y^2+\sqrt[3]2Y+\sqrt[3]{4})$ in $k$

Comment: Can I say $Y^3-2$ splits completely in $k[Y]$. Either way, as mentioned by runaway44, using CRT, I can get something like $k \otimes k \equiv k[Y]/(Y-\sqrt[3]2) \times k[Y]/(Y^2+\sqrt[3]2Y+\sqrt[3]{4})$. But I still don't see how can I involve $Q$ back into this again.

Comment: $k/\Bbb{Q}$ is not Galois, $Y^3-2$ doesn't split completely in $k[Y]$. Here $k\otimes_\Bbb{Q} k\cong k \times L$ where $L=k[Y]/(Y^2+\sqrt[3]2Y+\sqrt[3]{4})$ is a quadratic extension of $k$  (and the Galois closure of $k/\Bbb{Q}$ but it doesn't have to be the case away from cubic extensions)

Comment: But can I say something like $k \otimes k \equiv Q[X,Y]/(X^3-2)(Y^3-2)$. This being correct makes intuitive sense to me, but i am still not quite sure.